# Put navigation arrows on mobile in wordpress revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, mobile, slider

i need to know if it is possible to put the navigation arrows on the slider in mobile version of the site. I'm using revolution slider on Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they're disabled by default and there is no "single-click" solution to this. You can either modify the css (if you're familiar with it) as seen in this [post](https://theme-fusion.com/forums/reply/reply-to-revolution-slider-navigtion-arrows-in-mobile-view-not-showing/).

Or a more "hard-fashioned" approach would be to manually insert an arrow image in the slider, because although the arrow doesn't show up, the functionality of "tap the edge to navigate" still works.